# ConnectionError with Messenger bot

Tags: python, bots, facebook-messenger

I'm using messenger bot with pymessenger (here the link https://github.com/davidchua/pymessenger ).
Sometimes, when I try to send messages to the user using the bot.send_text_message() or one of the other functions to send messages of the python package, I got the following error:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymessenger\bot.py", line 29, in send_text_message
    return self._send_payload(payload)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymessenger\bot.py", line 76, in _send_payload
    result = requests.post(self.base_url, json=payload).json()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 111, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 57, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 585, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 467, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='graph.facebook.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2.6/me/messages?access_token=<my_token> (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000422A40B8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond',))
```

I thought that maybe I did too many requests to Facebook, but it's just me to use the bot and the number of requests I'm doing is the one of a normal chat so I guess it should be something else, but I don't get what.
I'm using ngrok for the callbacks.

Comment: Have you tried catching the `ConnectionError` and retrying the operation?

Comment: for the moment I'm not experiencing the issue anymore. I will update the post when I will recounter it to see if in this way I solve it

Answer (score 0):

try to catch the HTTPSConnectionPool exception and look into its args to see the details I mean something like

```
except HTTPSConnectionPool as e:
    e.args
```

Comment: this is what I have in e.args:
`<type 'tuple'>: (MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='graph.facebook.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2.6/me/messages?access_token=<my_token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000008367BA8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond',))",),)`